# Locating which methods in C/C++ libraries to link against on *NIX

Tags: c++, c, linux, linker

In the past, what has worked for me when I'm **very lazy** (for both Linux and Windows) was to just boldly use "grep -r" in each possible lib paths (i.e. /lib, /lib64, /usr/lib, etc) which I know the libs resides at, to see if I can guess which libs are the probable candidates to link against and make sure to add the "-L" paths and "-l" lib files.

For most of MSDN documented libraries, usually, Microsoft is nice enough to indicate which DLL's to link against, but for Linux it's a little more work (i.e. I need to possibly use search engine on multiple sites).  For example, let's take ntohl(), which [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740069(v=vs.85).aspx) kindly shows static .lib and dynamic .dll files I can link against (it would be nice to know the paths, but that I can 'find' later).  If I '[man 3 ntohl](https://linux.die.net/man/3/ntohl)' for example, the best it can tell me is that I need to #include [arpa/inet.h](https://linux.die.net/include/arpa/inet.h), but I'd still have to find out (for me, grep) which lib to link against (perhaps ntohl() is not a good example since it's usually part of libc.so, but please bear with me, the point is, I had to grep to find out it's on libc.so).

Q: What are the right (practiced) ways to locate methods of C/C++ libraries that will accurately tell me which binary files has the implementations for the method I want to link against?

NOTE: Please disregard the versions (i.e. libc-2.19.so vs libc-xx.so) and arch/target (i386-linux-gnu vs x86_64-linux-gnu), which is not as important as locating the correct lib files which has the actual implementations for linking.

Answer (score 1):

Typically, unless otherwise specified, all functions come from the default C or C++ library that the compiler will link with by default.

Otherwise, the expectation is that the manual page for the library function will explicitly indicate that a non-default library must be linked with. For example, [the manual page for pthread_create(3)](http://manpages.courier-mta.org/htmlman3/pthread_create.3.html) tells you that linking with `-lpthread` is required.

Of course, one has to be dependent on third party libraries providing adequate documentation, either by supplying traditional manual pages, with linking instructions of this manner, or via some other documentation. Quite often, the library's website will have documentation that explains how to use the library.

Linux is not controlled by a monolithic entity that imposes uniform documentation requirements.

Comment: I agree, similar to MSDN, man is a very reliable tool to use which may tell me which libs to link against.  But what other tools are there besides man, to find which libs to link against?

Comment: Too broad. On rpm-based distributions one can use `rpm -q -f` to find out which package a header file came from, then `rpm -q -l` to list all files in the package, which will presumably include the library files. One can also use `obdump -T` to search through all libraries, for ones that define a particular symbol.

Comment: Nice suggestions!  I too do similar thing with Gentoo via 'portageq owners' to find out where the header file(s) came from.  Similar approach applies to 'pkg-config --list-all' (or on BSD, 'pkg_info') and track backwards.  But all in all, it has always been quickest and most generic to just 'grep -lr' and if it did not help much, I'd dig further with other methods.  Also due to times when I have to manually 'make install' which may drop libs but not update package info, so I cannot rely on package info at times.  Thus, 'grep' seems to be the most generalized quick solution at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

Many packages use `pkg-config` or their own version like `mysql_config`.

You can add the flags to the compiler using those tools:

```
g++ $(pkg-config somelib --cflags) -o prog prog.cpp $(pkg-config somelib --libs)
```

Otherwise I use the package manager to tell be what libraries are contained in a given package and where they get installed to.

To discover what libraries are available through `pkg-config` use:

```
pkg-config --list-all
```

Use `man pkg-config` for more information.

Comment: I do not mean to target ntohl as my example but in order to use pkg-config I need to know which lib to link against, don't I? In your example,what would I replace 'somelib' with to figure out which lib has the implementation?